# How to add Access-Control-Expose-Headers in Nginx server?

Tags: http, nginx

I have added `add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' '*';` in my Nginx server. But still not able to get any response headers.

Comment: Please provide more detail about your nginx.conf file. Where did you place the `add_header` and have you tried restarting the Nginx service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Somewhere in your server or location block. Please note that * will not be acceptable here. You have to explicitly expose each custom header.

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Authorization,X-Custom-Header';
```

Comment: Exactly. I had to add each header explicitly.